# Write output from netcat to a file

Tags: bash, netcat

I'm currently trying to write a scan port result to a text file.

Here is the command I tried to use:

```
nc -vv -z localhost 1-80 > file.txt
```

This doesn't work (that is, the error messages from `nc` don't end up in `file.txt`).

But when I type `nc -vv -z localhost 80 > file.txt` it works.

I already know that there is an output but I can't write that to a file.

Comment: I heard that netcat output was stderr I tried '2>' too and even '2>&1' but it's still doesn't work

Comment: It's doesn't write the output in a .txt file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to direct both *stderr* and *stdout* into the file:

```
nc -vv -z localhost 1-80 > file.txt 2>&1
```

Running the command against just one port (`80`) didn't generate any messages to *stderr*, so writing *stdout* to the file was sufficient to capture everything. However, with a range of ports (`1-80`) we definitely get output written to *stderr*, so we need to capture that in addition to the redirect that captures *stdout*.